# Prevent batch modifiers dropping caret if it's in the filename

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bat script and the first arg passed in is:
`"C:\aaa^bbb\xxx^yyy.txt"`

I wish to get the file and and containing dir (head):

```
set winhead=%~dp1
set winfile=%~nx1
echo winhead: %winhead%
echo winfile: %winfile%
```

Prints

```
winhead: 'C:\aaabbb\'
winfile: 'xxxyyy.txt'
```

I see the carets `^` where dropped. Okay I will just escape them:

```
set Pathin=%1
set Pathin=%Pathin:^=^^%
echo Pathin: %Pathin%
```

Prints

```
Pathin: "C:\aaa^^bbb\xxx^^yyy.txt"
```

Now to extract filename and head:

```
set winhead=%~dpPathin%
set winfile=%~nxPathin%
```

or

```
set winhead=%~dpPathin
set winfile=%~nxPathin
```

Does not perform the modifier, but just returns the literal string. After some research I discovered the modifiers can only be used on args, i.e. `%1` in this case.

So is it a bug that the modifiers don't handle carets correctly? How does one extract parts of the full path for files one may have created in explorer (i.e. those which contain carets)?

Comment: well, I have to ask, what is the purpose of the carets in the string? do you actually have a directory `aaa^bbb` and file called `xxx^yyy.txt`?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I think that the `"C:\aaa^bbb\xxx^yyy.txt"` string perfectly represents the [mcve] rules. FYI, I actually have a lot of such weirdly named filesystem objects (mostly in `UnASCII Names` or `Unusual Names` directories and mainly for testing purposes, honestly said :))

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks, I am aware yes, I am just trying to understand the full context so I can understand what needs to be done, but there is an answer already. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change your input then pass `"C:\aaa^^^bbb\xxx^^^yyy.txt"` with the following:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "winhead=%~dp1"
Set "winfile=%~nx1"
Echo winhead: %winhead%
Echo winfile: %winfile%

Pause
```

If you cannot change the input, use `"C:\aaa^bbb\xxx^yyy.txt"` and enable delayed expansion:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "winhead=%~dp1"
Set "winfile=%~nx1"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo winhead: !winhead!
Echo winfile: !winfile!
EndLocal

Pause
```

Answer (score 3):

The `^` Circumflex Accent (so-called *caret*) works as an [Escape character](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html). If you need to take a caret literally in a variable, [escape it using double quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) (`set "winhead=%~dp1"`) and use it either using double quotes (`echo "%winhead%"`) or utilizing [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (`echo !winhead!`).

Sample script:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo supplied parameters: %*
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "winhead=%~dp1"
set "winfile=%~nx1"
echo winhead - percent expansion: %winhead% "%winhead%" 
echo winfile - percent expansion: %winfile% "%winfile%"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  echo winhead - delayed expansion: !winhead! "!winhead!"
  echo winfile - delayed expansion: !winfile! "!winfile!"
ENDLOCAL
```

**Output**: `.\SO\62849275.bat "C:\aaa^bbb\xxx^yyy.txt"`

> ```
> supplied parameters: "C:\aaa^bbb\xxx^yyy.txt"
> winhead - percent expansion: C:\aaabbb\ "C:\aaa^bbb\"
> winfile - percent expansion: xxxyyy.txt "xxx^yyy.txt"
> winhead - delayed expansion: C:\aaa^bbb\ "C:\aaa^bbb\"
> winfile - delayed expansion: xxx^yyy.txt "xxx^yyy.txt"
> ```

You can escape a caret using an additional caret (`"C:\aaa^^bbb\xxx^^yyy.txt"`), or utilize [`call` command](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) behaviour: *If the `CALL` command contains a caret character within a quoted string, the carets will be doubled*:

```
CALL .\SO\62849275.bat "C:\aaa^bbb\xxx^yyy.txt"
```

> ```
> supplied parameters: "C:\aaa^^bbb\xxx^^yyy.txt"
> winhead - percent expansion: C:\aaa^bbb\ "C:\aaa^^bbb\"
> winfile - percent expansion: xxx^yyy.txt "xxx^^yyy.txt"
> winhead - delayed expansion: C:\aaa^^bbb\ "C:\aaa^^bbb\"
> winfile - delayed expansion: xxx^^yyy.txt "xxx^^yyy.txt"
> ```

**Side note**. The `^` character (Circumflex Accent, U+005E) used to call *caret* for its visual similarity with the character `‸` (Caret, U+2038).

Comment: Great indepth answer thank you! I want to mark your as also the correct answer, but @compo got in there first. Thank you!